# How to log something to Zend Developer Tools toolbar?

Tags: zend-framework2, developer-tools

It's posible to log to Zend Developer Tools toolbar some variable in ZF2 controller?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I have created a Collector to add personal information on ZendDevelopersTool.
You need info from a Controller, and that's I never had tried to do. :)

I gonna show you how I created the Collector, and maybe you can find some way to take info from the Controller.

In your `MyModule\module.config.php`

```
/* ZendDeveloperTools Configuration */
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyModule\ConfigCollector'   => 'MyModule\Collector\ConfigCollector',
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'zend-developer-tools/toolbar/mymodule-configs' => __DIR__ . '/../view/zend-developer-tools/toolbar/mymodule-configs.phtml',
    ),
),

'zenddevelopertools' => array(
    'profiler' => array(
        'collectors' => array(
            'mymodule_configs' => 'MyModule\ConfigCollector',
        ),
    ),
    'toolbar' => array(
        'entries' => array(
            'mymodule_configs' => 'zend-developer-tools/toolbar/mymodule-configs',
        ),
    ),
),
```

On `MyModule\Module.php`, you need to load your invokables, I'm doing this by adding the following method:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

Add a `.phtml` file on the on your views:

```
MyModule/view/zend-developer-tools/toolbar/mymodule-configs.phtml
```

And add, for example:

```
<?php /* @var $collector \DoctrineORMModule\Collector\MappingCollector */ ?>
<div class="zdt-toolbar-entry">
    <div class="zdt-toolbar-preview">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="VnsDesenvolvimento">
        <span class="zdt-toolbar-info">
            Configurações Gerais
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="zdt-toolbar-detail">
        <span class="zdt-toolbar-info">
            <span class="zdt-detail-label">Environment</span>
            <span class="zdt-detail-value">
                <?php echo $this->collector->getEnvironment(); ?>
            </span>
        </span>

        <span class="zdt-toolbar-info">
            <span class="zdt-detail-label">Default Locale</span>
            <span class="zdt-detail-value">
                <?php echo $this->collector->getDefaultLocale(); ?>
            </span>
        </span>
        
        <span class="zdt-toolbar-info">
            <span class="zdt-detail-label">Time Zone</span>
            <span class="zdt-detail-value">
                <?php echo $this->collector->getTimeZone(); ?>
            </span>
        </span>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the final part!
We need to create a Collector, that gonna grab all teh information we wanna display:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Collector;

use ZendDeveloperTools\Collector;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

/**
 * Collector to be used in ZendDeveloperTools to record and display personal information
 *
 * @license MIT
 * @author  Vinicius Garcia <vinigar[...].com>
 */
class ConfigCollector extends \ZendDeveloperTools\Collector\AbstractCollector
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mymodule_configs';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getPriority()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function collect(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
    {
        $date = new \DateTime();
        
        $this->data = array(
            'environment' => ucfirst(getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: 'production'),
            'timezone' => $date->getTimezone()->getName(),
            'defaultlocale' => \Locale::getDefault(),
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the environment
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEnvironment()
    {
        return $this->data['environment'];
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the timezone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTimeZone()
    {
        return $this->data['timezone'];
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the default locale
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultLocale()
    {
        return $this->data['defaultlocale'];
    }
}
```

This Class have methods, like `getDefaultLocale()`, and we use them on `zend-developer-tools/toolbar/mymodule-configs.phtml`.

It should look like this:

[image: My Configs on ZendDeveloperTool]

You can try to adapt this piece of code, to fit your needs.
And please, if you find out how to grab info from your controller, share with us!

**Edit**

In the `ConfigCollector` class, pay attention to the method `collect(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)`.

As you can see, you have a MvcEvent object there. Maybe you can pass your personal info using it.

Comment: Important to notice, I based this solution looking on DoctrineORMModule... sadly there is no place where we can find good instructions on how to create AddOns for ZendDeveloperTools... :(

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'll check the DoctrineORMModule to see what's happening there.
I up vote your suggestions but I can't accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: So, I tried your example and it doesn't work. Probably I missed something or you forgot to mention some step. The problem is that $this->collector is null in view(.phtml) file. If you have any idea where is my mistake, please let me know.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the code. The Collector is not a view helper, you can access in your view using `$this->collector`...
If you did it right, and your ZendDevelopersTool is activate, the informations you create will automatic appears on the toolbar.

Comment: And make sure you had change in the code I posted here, all the namespaces to fit your own application.

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to mention that I didn't implement my stuff yet. I only copy paste your example code in my module and change namespace accordingly, but then I get an error that it can not access 'getEnvironment'(that line "<?php echo $this->collector->getEnvironment(); ?>" from .phtml file) method from a non object. And if I inspect "$this->collector" in .phtml file then is null. That is why I asked you if this are all the steps to make this example to work.

Comment: Also, if I remove all mentions in .phtml file to 'collector' object then the entry is displayed in the toolbar (like in your screen), but of course without any data. So the question is  - why the collector object isn't injected in the view?

Comment: Well, I just now realize that I forgot the `use ZendDeveloperTools\Collector;` in ConfigCollector class! :O I change my answer to include it. See if this makes the code works. Sorry for this bug. ^^

Comment: Well... It's one word - fp(facepalm, maybe two).
My mistake was that the name in getName method was different from key in configuration. If I wouldn't be so lazy and start to debug from beginning, when I would found that days ago. 
PS: Thanks for waisting your time with me.

Answer (score 2):

More briefly, it's possible : )
I'm not proud about the way I did it, but - well known excuse - it works.
And if you have any suggestions, I'll be not glad but happy to hear them.

How to create a custom collector @vinigarcia87 explained above.

To log something in Controller(and in any other place) and then grab that data in the collector I made a new class in my module with a static field and static getter/setter, which I use as a proxy. Here is some code:

```
namespace MyModule\Log;

class MyLogger {
    private static $messages = array();

    public static function log($message)
    {
        self::$messages[] = $message;
    }
    public static function getMessages()
    {
        return self::$messages;
    }
}
```

In a controller's action:

```
MyModule\Log\Logger::log('Informational message');
```

And in collector collect method:

```
public function collect(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    $this->data = array(
        'messages'     => MyModule\Log\Logger::getMessages(),
    );
}
public function getMessages()
{
    return $this->data['messages'];
}
```

This messages are now accessible in toolbar entry .pthml file this way:
 `<?php \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($this->collector->getMessages()); ?>`

Your opinions...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use my package that alow log any data to bar and use Tracy/Debugger to highlight and add tree to your dumped data.

[renat-magadiev/zf3-bar-logger](https://packagist.org/packages/renat-magadiev/zf3-bar-logger)

so you can simply write:

```
<?php

\BarLogger\Collector\DebugCollector::barDump(['testing dump' => ['asd', 'asdad', 'fdgfdsg', 'gfgsd']], 'testing dump');

?>
```

or simply using global function in shortcuts:

```
<?php

barDump(['testing dump' => ['asd', 'asdad', 'fdgfdsg', 'gfgsd']], 'testing dump');

?>
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tQoi.png)