# Add Collector to ZendDeveloperTools

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The question had answered but solution doesn't work and I don't know why : [How to log something to Zend Developer Tools toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325842/how-to-log-something-to-zend-developer-tools-toolbar/23248544#23248544)

I open a new Question because I can't comment and I can't reply to ask help (it's avoid, right ?)

So, I wanna add a collector to ZendDeveloperTools to display some variables. So I tried code and I got this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Unable to fetch or create an instance for Modsession\ConfigCollector.

And I put this in my `Modsession/config/module.config.php`

```
'invokables' => array(
    'Modsession\ConfigCollector'           => 'Modsession\Collector\ConfigCollector',
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'zend-developer-tools/toolbar/modsession-configs' => __DIR__ . '/../view/zend-developer-tools/toolbar/modsession-configs.phtml',
    ),
),

'zenddevelopertools' => array(
    'profiler' => array(
        'collectors' => array(
            'modsession_configs' => 'Modsession\ConfigCollector',
        ),
    ),
    'toolbar' => array(
        'entries' => array(
            'modsession_configs' => 'zend-developer-tools/toolbar/modsession-configs',
        ),
    ),
),
```

I don't see that is wrong, all names are correct, but it doesn't find it so I don't understand

Thanks for you reply and to explain me my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is indeed your `module.config.php` you're missing the `service_manager` key which should be wrapping your array of `invokables`...

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Modsession\ConfigCollector' => 'Modsession\Collector\ConfigCollector',
    ),
),
```