# How to add custom debug data to ZendDebugToolbar

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using the [ZendDebugToolbar](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) and it displays fine on the app, however, how do I send custom debug data to it? For example if I want to dump some key session information to it or a simple var_dump ?

Comment: See my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325842/how-to-log-something-to-zend-developer-tools-toolbar/20351809#20351809

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the [ZFDebug](https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug).

Since ZFDebug operates as a front-controller plugin that fires only on `dispatchLoopShutdown()`, it really only has access to variables that are available there, typically long-lived singleton instances from classes like `Zend_Registry`, `Zend_Controller_Front` (so you can get the request and response objects), etc. There is really no mechanism for direct communication between internal processes - like models and controllers - and the ZFDebug plugin.

So, for the kind of debugging about which you ask - `var_dump()` of your own custom variables and introspecting session data, presumably in other parts of system like  services, controllers, models, etc - it might be easiest to simply add that data to `Zend_Registry` and then examine it later in ZFDebug under the `Variables` tab.

However, if you really want to add something new to the ZFDebug interface itself, then you can use its own internal plugin system to add tabs/panels to its interface.

It looks like you can simply create a class that implements the interface `ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug_Plugin_Interface` ([link](https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug/blob/master/library/ZFDebug/Controller/Plugin/Debug/Plugin/Interface.php)) and then register your custom plugin with the main `$debug` object during bootstrap.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * See some of the other plugin implementations for examples of what could go into each of 
 * these methods. 
 */
class My_ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_SomePlugin implements ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug_Plugin_Interface
{

    /**
     * Has to return html code for the menu tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTab()
    {
        // @todo
    }

    /**
     * Has to return html code for the content panel
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPanel()
    {
        // @todo
    }

    /**
     * Has to return a unique identifier for the specific plugin
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIdentifier()
    {
        // @todo
    }


    /**
     * Return the path to an icon
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIconData()
    {
        // @todo
    }
}
```

Then in `Bootstrap`:

```
protected function _initZFDebug()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('ZFDebug');

    $options = array(
        'plugins' => array('Variables', 
                           'Database' => array('adapter' => $db), 
                           'File' => array('basePath' => '/path/to/project'),
                           'Cache' => array('backend' => $cache->getBackend()), 
                           'Exception')
    );
    $debug = new ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug($options);

    // register your custom sub-plugin
    $debug->registerPlugin(new My_ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_SomePlugin());

    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $frontController->registerPlugin($debug);
}
```

As usual, you will have to have autoloading in place for the namespace `My_` or whatever you use for your custom class.

Remember, the same constraint as before applies: the only data available to your plugins are the long-lived instances that you can statically pull out of the ether; things like `Zend_Registry`, `Zend_Controller_Front` (hence request/response), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated response but I am not sure if that will work, I am referring to Zend-Developer-Tools ToolBar found here https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools  I am also using in ZF2 not ZF1  ... however I will review it to see if it works relatively similar.

Comment: D'oh! OK, sorry. I have added the link to the question and added a zf2 tag. Doesn't look like the ZDT has the same kind of plugin structure. But it does seem to have a section of config where you can specify "collectors": https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools/blob/master/config/zenddevelopertools.local.php.dist#L134  Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

@vinygarcia87 is the right answer. 
Could not select it as the right answer because you typed it as a comment.